# Running out of memory when exporting at high ImageResolution

Tags: graphics, export, memory, rendering, rasterize

```
plot = Grid[
   Partition[
    Table[Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {k, 0, 6, 0.1}], 8], 
   Frame -> All];
MaxMemoryUsed[Export["p.jpg", plot, ImageResolution -> 480]]/1024/1024.
```

> 430.894

I can export it with a **480ppi** resolution normally, and the `MMA` just costs 430M memory as the output. My computer has 32G RAM, but when I change the `ImageResolution` into **500** I will get a error about out of memory for `Rasterize`. Why? It's unreasonable. I want to export this image with 600 or 700 ppi.

---

If the explain of @[ihojnicki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18638/ihojnicki) is reasonable, then we will think the FrontEnd have a fixed-maximun memory to use. But let us change the `plot` to export:

```
 Clear["`*"]
F[x_, k_] := -400/x^k;

equ[k_] := {\[Rho]''[t] - \[Theta]'[t]^2*\[Rho][t] == 
    F[\[Rho][t], k], \[Theta]''[t]*\[Rho][t] + 
     2*\[Theta]'[t]*\[Rho]'[t] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0, \[Rho][0] == 
    1, \[Rho][0] \[Theta]'[0] == 10, \[Rho]'[0] == 10};

sol[k_] := NDSolve[equ[k], {\[Theta], \[Rho]}, {t, 0, 10}];

plot = Grid[
   Partition[
    Table[ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[{\[Rho][t]*Cos[\[Theta][t]], \[Rho][t]*
          Sin[\[Theta][t]]} /. First[sol[k]]], {t, 0, 10}, 
      PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
      PlotLabel -> "label \[Alpha]=" <> ToString[k], 
      FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], {k, -3.6, 2.7, 0.1}], 8], 
   Frame -> All];

MaxMemoryUsed[Export["p.jpg", plot, ImageResolution -> 650]]/
  1024/1024.
```

> 1104.06

Note I can use nearly 1G memory now. But when I change the 650ppi into 700ppi I will get a same error about out of memory. Isn't the limit fixed?

Comment: I also get this issue with that code snippet (changing `ImageResolution` to 500) on my machine, which has 96 gigabytes of RAM. I wonder if it is something other than a memory issue...

Comment: (You can reproduce this without creating a file by just doing `Rasterize[plot, ImageResolution -> 500]`)

Comment: Interesting: `Export["p.png", Show@plot, ImageResolution -> 500]` works just fine, even though it complains that `Grid is not a type of Graphics`. I wonder if there's some sort of check against the Head of the expression to be rasterized. (Though it does again begin to fail at `ImageResolution -> 680`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with system memory.  System textures have limits, both in pixel dimensions and overall video memory used.  On Windows, at least, the FrontEnd's threshold is set a little lower than the actual limits of D3D.  Even if they were the same though, this example still would overflow well before reaching 600ppi.

Comment: How to adjust this limits?

Comment: These limits cannot be adjusted.

Comment: The limit is not a fixed value? Note the question supplement. I noticed that the errors were reported at different memory usage levels

Comment: I guess you could render the subparts and then splice the images together again. See https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/848646 the last two paragraphs that i wrote. I see you used Grid so you would have to use show and use insets to place the plots or used GraphicsGrid perhaps.

Comment: @yode, perhaps this code chunk would better explain the particular limit you are running into.   ```CanFitToday[content_, ppi_] := 
 Module[{result = Quiet@Rasterize[content, ImageResolution -> 72]}, 
  If[FailureQ[result], False, 
   Max[ImageDimensions[result]] * ppi / 72 <= 15000]]```

Comment: GraphicsGrid will lead to some strange problem like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28InH.png), this is why I abandon it..